# What is the explanation of infinite summation of random walk matrix?

Tags: graph-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process, random-walk, stochastic-analysis

I'm reading about Katz index, I wonder what is the explanation about Katz index in intuitive meaning ?
How about I replace a random walk matrix, i.e., use probability instead of adjacency indicator. Is there realistic meaning about matrix $S$ defined as follows:
$$
S = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\alpha^iP^i
$$
where $\alpha\in (0,1)$ and $P=D^{-1}A$, $A$ is the adjacency matrix in Katz index, and $ D$ is the diagonal matrix with degree of $A$.

Comment: What do you mean by a geometric meaning? Where is geometry coming into this to begin with?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Sorry, I didn't use the right word, I just wanted to express the "intuitive meaning", because usually geometry is more intuitive.